# How to execute the diff command with two output redirection by python subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I would like to execute the command,`"diff < command1 < command2"` with subprocess.run(). command1 & command2 are much like "ssh-keygen -y -e -f file1". command1 & command2 will print to stdout.
I got error message as below, "diff: conflicting output style options".
I'v tried several ways but failed to got it through.
Any comments?

Comment: Please provide code snippet, I suspect you are passing command1 as  `ssh-keygen -y -e -f file1` instead of `"ssh-keygen -y -e -f file1"` (Note the `"`)

Comment: I execute ```subprocess.run("diff < ssh-keygen -y -f key1 < ssh-keygen -y -f key2", shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)```.

Comment: Change it to `subprocess.run("diff < 'ssh-keygen -y -f key1' < 'ssh-keygen -y -f key2'", shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` this might work.

Comment: It doesn't work here. In the end, I have to divide it into two commands.